# Error con validación de usuarios con Active Directory

Tags: c#, validación, iis, directorioactivo

Un proyecto Web usa validación de `Active Directory`, está publicado en IIS7 en windows 7 en un servidor virtual. Todo marchaba bien, servía normal, pero yo cometí el error de darle `ipconfig /release` a la ip del servidor "yo me conecto remoto". Luego de devolverle la IP, el `Active Directory` solo me presenta este error y no sé qué será, he revisado muchas cosas pero nada parece ser la solución, soy un principiante en esto.

El problema es con el servidor que estoy usando porque localmente en mi computadora el sistema si valida bien los usuarios del `Active Directory` y entra con normalidad.

¿Alguien tiene idea de qué puede ser el problema? Porque la verdad me siento amarrado no sé qué es, he intentado varias cosas y nada funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si será eso, pero yo diria que te falta añadir un usuario y contraseña en esa cadena. Intenta añadir algo como `connectionUsername="cn=usuario"
         connectionPassword="password"`

Comment: lo que me extraña es porque exige eso ahora y antes no?, y pues ya le agregué eso y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: el error es el mismo?

Comment: Hmm..estoy pensando otra cosa. Si tienes acceso al IIS, intenta poner el modo de autenticacion a Windows

Comment: Sí, de hecho ya lo he hecho antes y sigue igual, y el error es el mismo.

Comment: Intenta deshabilitar la Basic authentication

Comment: Hola, Puedes mostrarnos la cadena de conexión con nombre ADConnectionString? Lo digo es por si llegas a la dirección indicada. Tal vez tengas problemas de DNS a la hora de resolver nombres. Intenta acceder por IP al AD